# Set QGraphicsTextItem origin in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

If I want to place one letter (a QGraphicsTextItem) in a QGraphicsView, is there any way I can set the text to display in the middle of the coordinates I specify? If I use `QGraphicsTextItem.setPos(x,y)`, it treats the (x,y) as the top-left corner. I still want the top-left of the QGraphicsScene to remain as (0, 0), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the [boundingRect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicstextitem.html#boundingRect) method of your QGraphicsTextItem to calculate the height and width of your letter and then shift position of the QGraphicsTextItem to make it look like it's centered around x,y coordinates. Smth like this:

```
QGraphicsTextItem* textItem0 = new QGraphicsTextItem("Test Text Item", 0, scene);
int x = x - textItem0->boundingRect().width() / 2;
int y = y - textItem0->boundingRect().height() / 2;
textItem0->setPos(x, y);
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: It's about 1 pixel off horizontally, but that's probably the font's problem. Thanks.